# Azure Policy - Configure backup on virtual machines with a given tag

Tags: azure, policy, azure-policy

I wonder if somebody could sanity check something for me with this please in case it's something I could be missing.

We have this existing policy configured in a customers tenant (https://www.azadvertizer.net/azpolicyadvertizer/345fa903-145c-4fe1-8bcd-93ec2adccde8.html

After creating a VM and allocating the correct tag etc. it didn't automatically have the backup policy assigned to it. With the policy assignment itself it didn't even appear as a non-compliant resource. I went through the checks to make sure it was the same region, correct tag, correct rsv and policy, which all appeared to look fine. When remediating it still wasn't pulling the resource through.

When I went into the definition detail to see what could be amiss, I noticed the list of WindowServer image SKU's that were listed (image attached here.

[image]

As I was sanity checking everything, I looked at the VM to see that the SKU wasn't actually in this list (2019-datacenter-smalldisk-g2).

As every SKU is listed specifically it makes me think this image has just been missed off and needs adding? Rather than it getting captured by one of the SKU's listed.

I can add the VM manually to the existing RSV for now but for future ref, is there a way I can raise this if my findings are indeed correct?

Answer (score 0):

> As I was sanity checking everything, I looked at the VM to see that the SKU wasn't actually in this list (2019-datacenter-smalldisk-g2).

The default policy will trigger the backup only if **VM SKUs** are matched, but the **2019-datacenter-smalldisk-g2** **VM SKU** is not in the default list, and we cannot edit the **default policy** to add more **SKUs** to it

To add required **VM SKU's** in existing default policy, you may **duplicate** the definition.

[image]

You may add required **SKU's** and save the definition.

[image]

Add the tag details in parameter to configure backup on **virtual machines** with tag.

[image]

Create a **remediation** task as below.

[image]

The policy detected the non-compliance **VM's** and also created **Recovery Service Vault** with **backup policy**.

[image]

**Recovery Service vault created.**

[image]

Comment: Hi Venkat, Thanks for your response.
Is there any way this can be raised to MS to your knowledge to get these or future sku's added to the default policy? Seems overkill that we would need to perform this task for each of our customers in the scenario they may create a vm using a sku outside of this list in the future.

Comment: Yes, you can raise support request to MS for same or create your own policy by adding required **sku's** as per requirement.